# SQL Server 2022 won't accept new login password

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

For my CI/CD pipeline, I spin up a docker instance of SQL Server to run integration tests against.

I've always used the `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest-ubuntu` image (which appears to use Server 2017). I updated to the `2022-latest` tag.

However, my script for setting up the database is failing at this line:

```sql
USE [master]

CREATE LOGIN CICD WITH PASSWORD = '!CICD_builder_pipeline!';
GO
```

The error I get is the same, no matter how long or complicated I make the password:

> [2023-11-30 12:21:01] [S0002][33064] Line 3: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols.

For what it's worth, this is the docker compose file for standing up the database image:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  mssql_acs:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: mssql_acs
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/docker-sql-server-entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
      - ./ddl/sql-server-init.sql:/db-init.sql
    networks:
      - mssql_acs

networks:
  mssql_acs:
    name: mssql_acs
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can you not use a stronger password with symbols? Altenatively, if you must, try adding with check_policy = off as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Wouldn't the exclamation points and underscores count as special characters? This is a temporary database that is destroyed once so I am not concerned about using a low-security password. However, when I tested the password `k8soe3E^ERFGfl^94QS%ex@j` ,it worked okay so there must be some undocumented additional checks on the password complexity in versions above 2017.

Comment: Among other things `!` is the history expansion character in most shells. Compare what happens when you execute `docker run -it --rm -e "SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest /bin/bash -c export` (you get a `-bash: !: event not found` error) versus when you execute `docker run -it --rm -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest /bin/bash -c export` (you see your password in the container's environment variables).

Comment: Aside... [Configure SQL Server settings with environment variables on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-environment-variables) _The `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable is deprecated. Use `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` instead._